# Word for a combination of video / visuals / perhaps other media

Tags: single-word-requests

I believe it was about one year ago that I listened to a song (title is “Hún Jörð” by the band Sigur Rós) on YouTube accompanied by video. I believe the video was taken from a film about Jesus and Christianity. The author used a term for this kind of combination of audio and  visual, but I can’t remember it. Could anybody help me out?

**Edit**: When I looked up the word back then, I believe one of the definitions was something along the lines of “two things moving together” or “two things playing in harmony”.

Comment: Is montage the word you're looking for?

Comment: No it's not, unfortunately.

Comment: Is it _concord_ ?

Comment: Sounds like *tandem* to me.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are referring to [syncronize:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synchronize) (from Merriam-Webster Dic.)

> - to make (motion-picture sound) exactly simultaneous with the action.

- How to [Sync](http://thinkinghard.com/blog/HowToSyncVideoAndSeparatelyRecordedAudio.html) Video and Separately Recorded Audio, Using Only Open-Source Software

Source: www.thinkinghard.com

Answer (score 0):

When media from multiple sources are combined or adapted, these are often called ***mashups***.

> [*mashup*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mash-up): a mixture or fusion of disparate elements.
> (Source: Oxford Dictionaries)

A well-known mashup is [Dark Side of the Rainbow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Side_of_the_Rainbow), which combines Pink Floyd's *The Dark Side of the Moon* with V. Flemming's 1939 film *The Wizard of Oz*.

Comment: I don't like this answer because too many people use `mashup` to represent the interleaving of the same media type, e.g., mixing Rock and Dubstep. When I think of `mashup` I immediately think of this definition because it's so common on Youtube. In fact as further evidence of this, that Wikipedia article goes out of the way to specify "music video mashup".